# This can stop you from dripping

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

Considering how quickly my last 'Riley Riddle' was solved, I thought I'd try again:

> My prefix causes you trouble;
> My suffix, people have double.
> My infix, you find swimming;
> This can stop you from dripping.

**What am I?**

Comment: Could the suffix be Rot13(evat)? Because you can wear that (1) on your *evat* finger (2), hence double :P

Answer (score 5):

> An ink blotter.

Prefix:

> A blot or stain might get you in trouble with your mom

(I'm not sure how the suffix part works)

Infix:

> an otter you find swimming and a blotter stops ink from running or dripping.

Comment: You got part of it right! :)

Comment: Otter is actually forming the "suffix" , not the "infix" . This should be an altogether wrong approach.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be

> Pottering.

Prefix:

> Pot. Gets you in trouble.

Infix:

> Otter. Swims.

Suffix:

> Ring. The only one not sure about. Perhaps "people have double" because you often buy two rings, like in marriage?

Answer (score 2):

> false alarm

my prefix causes you trouble

> being false

my suffix people have double

> arm

my infix you find swimming

> seal

this can stop you from dripping

> a true alarm will make the firemen spray water, but this won't

Comment: Weak, I admit .

Answer (score -3):

I think the answer is:

> **feelings**

my prefix causes you trouble

> **fee** -- fees give people trouble.

my suffix people have double

> **lings** -- is close to lungs. People have double lungs.

my infix you find swimming

> **eel** -- a type of fish.

this can stop you from dripping

> you go to the bathroom when your **feelings** tell you you need to.